# PHP - How to remove trailing variables from Form Submit?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When I submit a form, I get url's that look like this `http://localhost/offstreams/search/?search=fuzz`. I want the URL to look like so: `http://localhost/offstreams/search/fuzz`.

Here is my HTML Form:

```
<form action="<?php echo BASE_URI . "search/"; ?>" method='get' class='searchbarForm'>
    <input type='text' name='search' id='searchbar' placeholder='Search...'/>
</form>
```

My PHP Code:

```
if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
    echo $_GET['search'];   
}
```

My .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ ./offstreams/searchs/search.php?search=$1 [QSA]
```

**HERE'S THE THING:**
The result is printed when I go to `http://localhost/offstreams/search/fuzz` - It works absolutely fine, BUT I want the page to submit to that link instead of the ugly URL from the top. **How do I submit a form and have the *$_GET['search']* to work with mod_rewrite?**

Comment: do you have to use GET or can you use POST?

Comment: you would need to use javascript and on click of the search/submit button, change the form's action attribute to include the value of the search box. Likely I would change the submit button to a "button" button (so it doesn't submit) and then in my buttons click handler function handle the navigation myself like `location.href=encodeURIComponent(value);`.

Comment: Most frameworks use a Route and { Slug } solution. Theres probably some hacky function you can do to strip and read a normal url

Comment: @bassxzero Using post works, but doesn't display it in the url, which I don't like because I don't want search data to disappear if the user goes to a new page an clicks the back button or something of that nature.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you were asking but it should work.

```
if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
    if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?') !== false) {
       header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/offstreams/search/'.urlencode($_GET['search']));
       exit();
    }
    echo $_GET['search'];   
}
```

This will search for a `?` in the current url and then format the url to the way you want it.